# Heroku rake db:migrate aborts; interning empty string... why?

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rake

Ok I've tried searching this site for other similar questions, but those that come close have no answers, so hopefully a rails/heroku guru can help me out.

I've created a basic rails app (I'm learning) and managed to have it run on my home machine perfectly. But when I push it to Heroku and type:

`heroku rake db:migrate` I get the following error/s:

```
c:\iltapp>heroku rake db:migrate --trace
rake aborted!
interning empty string
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1309:in `to_sym'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1309:in `action_path'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1304:in `path_for_action'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1159:in `match'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1360:in `match'
/app/config/routes.rb:11
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:233:in `instance_exec'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:233:in `draw'
/app/config/routes.rb:1
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:227:in `load_dependency'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:127:in `reload_routes!'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:127:in `each'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:127:in `reload_routes!'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:120:in `routes_reloader'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:32:in `call'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:32:in `execute_if_updated'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:51
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:52:in `call'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:52
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `run_initializers'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
/app/config/environment.rb:5
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:216:in `initialize_tasks'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:607:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `each'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:596:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/usr/ruby1.8.7/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/ruby1.8.7/bin/rake:19
(in /app)
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
```

Sorry for the long paste, but to be honest I don't know which part of that might me informative. What I have noticed and I hope this isnt the case is I have `Ruby 1.9.2` & `Rails 3` installed and I see heroku mentions `1.8` above. Would my code be totally incompatible with heroku if I stay with my version or if that is the issue, is there a way around it?

**Update #1:** I tried @Svilen's suggestion of reseting the db with `herolu rake db:reset` and get the same error and some new ones, which may or may not be related. And to clarify I am runnign it on a **Bamboo Stack (bamboo-ree-1.8.7)** Heres what i get:

```
Couldn't drop hvjiqvwyxn : #<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  must be owner of database hvjiqvwyxn
: DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS "hvjiqvwyxn">
hvjiqvwyxn already exists
rake aborted!
interning empty string
```

**Update #2:** As per @Svilen's mention of the stacks I have migrated to **bamboo-mri-1.9.2** where ruby 1.9.2 (and correct me if I'm wrong) supports "interning an empty string"

Any answers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku support Ruby 1.9.2 only on the Bamboo stack. You can check which stack you are using by typing **heroku stack**. If you are on the old one - Aspen - you can easily move to Bamboo. Check this article in Heroku's Dev Center: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack

If that's not the case, try resetting the database and forcing all migrations (note: you will lose all existing data!) with **heroku rake db:reset**. You can also try restarting Heroku beforehand with **heroku restart**.

If you noticed anything strange during your git push to heroku, it might be relevant to the problem and worth updating your question with additional data.

Comment: thank you very much for that info, I'm just learning ruby, rails adn heroku and that stumbling block would have prevented me from continuing for a long while, but its now fixed (see updates)